# Returning a hidden <td> value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It has many more rows in the tbody with actual values in the actual example (it adds results from an API depending on a search).

I would like to click a row and I want the value of the track ID  in that row to be returned, by `console.log` to begin with. It is hidden in CSS:

```js
$("tbody").click(function() {
  var $songId = $(this).closest("tr").find(".hidden").text();
  console.log($songId);
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="song-table" id="results-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="subtitle-text">Track</th>
      <th class="subtitle-text">Artist</th>
      <th class="subtitle-text">Album</th>
      <th class="hidden" id="song-id">ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="search-results-body">
    <tr>
      <td>Track name </td>
      <td>Artist name </td>
      <td>Album name </td>
      <td class="hidden">Track ID </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Track name </td>
      <td>Artist name </td>
      <td>Album name </td>
      <td class="hidden">Track ID </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Track name </td>
      <td>Artist name </td>
      <td>Album name </td>
      <td class="hidden">Track ID </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This returns as blank in the console, which I guess it because technically there is no text that exists. If I use `html()` instead it returns 'undefined'.

Can anywhere help me return the value of the hidden row?

Comment: Your example doesn’t work because you assign the click handler to the tbody instead of the rows or cells it contains.  The `this` keyword in your handler refers to the tbody element, which has no `.closest("tr")` (oops, as @MaxVollmer explained in his answer) (you would need to assign the handler to the `td` elements for `closest` to work).

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to click a row and I want the value of the track ID in that row to be returned

Then you have to attach the event to the row `tr` like:

```js
$("tr").click(function() {
  var $songId = $(this).find(".hidden").text();

  console.log($songId);
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="song-table" id="results-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="subtitle-text">Track</th>
      <th class="subtitle-text">Artist</th>
      <th class="subtitle-text">Album</th>
      <th class="hidden" id="song-id">ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="search-results-body">
    <tr>
      <td>Track name </td>
      <td>Artist name </td>
      <td>Album name </td>
      <td class="hidden">Track ID 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Track name </td>
      <td>Artist name </td>
      <td>Album name </td>
      <td class="hidden">Track ID 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Track name </td>
      <td>Artist name </td>
      <td>Album name </td>
      <td class="hidden">Track ID 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is it. Turns out I had also forgotten to close a quotation mark which was really confusing me. Many thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help bro, if the answer is what you're looking for Mark it as the **[correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** for the future readers.

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery docs about [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .closest() method searches through **these elements and their ancestors** in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

So you never actually get a `tr` element inside your table, because you are essentially telling it to look for a parent `tr` of your table, which obviously doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```js
$("tbody td").click(function(){
    var $songId = $(this).closest("tr").find(".hidden").text();
    console.log($songId);
});
```

```css
.hidden {

  display:none;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="song-table" id ="results-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="subtitle-text">Track</th>
                            <th class="subtitle-text">Artist</th>
                            <th class="subtitle-text">Album</th>
                            <th class="hidden" id="song-id">ID</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="search-results-body">
                      <tr>
              <td>Track name </td>
              <td>Artist name </td>
              <td>Album name </td>
              <td class="hidden">Track ID 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Track name </td>
              <td>Artist name </td>
              <td>Album name </td>
              <td class="hidden">Track ID 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Track name </td>
              <td>Artist name </td>
              <td>Album name </td>
              <td class="hidden">Track ID 3</td>
            </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```js
$(document).on('click','#results-table tr',function(){
     var allTd=$(this).find('td');
        
        $.each(allTd,function(i,td){
        debugger;
         if($(td).hasClass('hidden'))
            {
             alert($(td)[0].innerText);
                console.log($(td)[0].innerText)
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.hidden {

  display:none;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="song-table" id ="results-table" border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="subtitle-text">Track</th>
                            <th class="subtitle-text">Artist</th>
                            <th class="subtitle-text">Album</th>
                            <th class="hidden" id="song-id">ID</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="search-results-body">
                      <tr>
              <td>Track name </td>
              <td>Artist name </td>
              <td>Album name </td>
              <td class="hidden">Track ID 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Track name </td>
              <td>Artist name </td>
              <td>Album name </td>
              <td class="hidden">Track ID 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Track name </td>
              <td>Artist name </td>
              <td>Album name </td>
              <td class="hidden">Track ID 3</td>
            </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find by class name on click table row like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'tbody tr', function(){
        var id = $(this).find('.hidden').text();
        alert(id)
    })
});
</script>
<style>
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="song-table" border="1" id="results-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="subtitle-text">Track</th>
      <th class="subtitle-text">Artist</th>
      <th class="subtitle-text">Album</th>
      <th class="hidden" id="song-id">ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="search-results-body">
    <tr>
      <td>Track name </td>
      <td>Artist name </td>
      <td>Album name </td>
      <td class="hidden">Track ID 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Track name </td>
      <td>Artist name </td>
      <td>Album name </td>
      <td class="hidden">Track ID 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Track name </td>
      <td>Artist name </td>
      <td>Album name </td>
      <td class="hidden">Track ID 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```